# what is the proper way to kill update-manager hung installing the 3.2.0-40 kernel?

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

Update-manager is hung bringing my 12.04 up to the 3.2.0-40 kernel. 
The cancel button is greyed out.
Is it safe and adequate to click the x icon? If not, what sequence to kill the hierarchy of processes, as listed below.

The window says: 
Applying changes
Configuring linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic-pae

Details window:

Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic-pae (3.2.0-40.64) ...

Running depmod.

update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)

Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.

run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.2.0-40-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic-pae

run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-40-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic-pae

The process hierarchy is:

dakra     2623     1  0 12:10 ?        00:00:08 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/update-manager

dakra     2646  2312  0 12:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/evolution/3.2/evolution-alarm-notify

dakra     2663     1  0 12:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon

dakra     2698  2312  0 12:11 ?        00:00:00 update-notifier

root      2704     1  0 12:11 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/aptd

root      2730     1  0 12:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/system-service/system-service-d

root      2755  2704  0 12:11 pts/2    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/aptd

dakra     3011  2623  0 12:12 ?        00:00:00 [debconf-communi]

root      3420  2755  0 12:12 pts/3    00:00:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 20 --configure linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic-pae:i386 linux-image-generic-pae:i386 linux-headers-3.2.0-40:all linux-headers-3.2.0-40-generic-pae:i386 linux-headers-generic-pae:i386 linux-generic-pae:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386 thunderbird:i386 thunderbird-globalmenu:i386 thunderbird-locale-en:i386 thunderbird-gnome-support:i386 thunderbird-locale-en-us:all

root      3421  3420  0 12:12 pts/3    00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic-pae.postinst configure

root      3445  3421  0 12:12 pts/3    00:00:00 run-parts --verbose --exit-on-error --arg=3.2.0-40-generic-pae --arg=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic-pae /etc/kernel/postinst.d

root      3474  3445  0 12:12 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller start 3.2.0-40-generic-pae

root      3476  3474  0 12:12 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/sbin/dkms autoinstall --kernelver 3.2.0-40-generic-pae

root      4228  3476  0 12:12 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/sbin/dkms autoinstall --kernelver 3.2.0-40-generic-pae

dakra     4869  2312  0 12:12 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/deja-dup/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor

root      7485  4228  0 12:12 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/sbin/dkms autoinstall --kernelver 3.2.0-40-generic-pae

root      7487  7485 99 12:12 pts/3    00:22:56 /sbin/depmod -a 3.2.0-40-generic-pae -F /boot/System.map-3.2.0-40-generic-pae

Comment: How long have you waited ? Best to let it run.

Comment: It's been about 90 minutes. new kernel levels, including the grub cycles for generic then generic-pae usually take maybe a minute after download.

Comment: You can try to kill the process or reboot (choose an old kernel). After you do, open a terminal and manually run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, see what if any errors you get.

Comment: Thank you. I

(1) killed the processes. 

(2) sudo apt-get upgrade 

(3) Synaptic package manager reinstall of the 3.2.0-40 items 

(4) shutdown & reboot with 3.2.0-40

All's well.